# xnamath with directx11 picking ray incorrect

Tags: c++, xna, directx, direct3d, directx-11

I'm trying to implement picking in my application but I just can't get it to work. I've tried 3 different ways of creating my picking ray but in every one the same problem persists. This is the one I finally went with:

```
    XMVECTOR screenpoint = XMVectorSet(x, y, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR dirvec = XMVector3Unproject(screenpoint, 0.0f, 0.0f, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f, mCam.Proj(), mCam.View(), XMMatrixIdentity());
    XMVECTOR RayDir = dirvec - mCam.GetPositionXM();
    RayDir = XMVector3Normalize(RayDir);
```

and use this to check for collision for triangles in a cube:

```
XNA::IntersectRayTriangle(mCam.GetPositionXM(), RayDir, v0, v1, v2, &t);
```

In all cases it will pick triangles that are covered by other triangles in certain cases. When the camera is right in front of one of the faces of the cube and it aims at the right half of that face it gets it kind of right, but when it aims at the left side it picks the face left of it.

My world transform is simple a matrixIdentity and I don't do anything special. I'm not sure as to what part of my code I should post so please ask if it's not clear enough to solve the problem. I load my vertices from a simple .obj file and I've checked to contents in the buffer and there are no translations or transforms anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to set the w-component of `screenpoint` to 1. Also I don't really understand your problem. Does it return wrong positives or just wrong orders?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Setting the w-component to 1 had no effect. It returns wrong positives, as it doesn't hit the cube where I aim it. I've tried just copy/pasting working code from an example but the same problem persists. I've tried removing the window borders as I've read that it could mess up coordinates.

Comment: Have you made sure that you work with the current (not outdated) data? Especially `mCam.Proj()`, `mCam.View()`, `mCam.GetPositionXM()`. What value is written into `t`? Have you printed the coordinates to a console? Top left should be (0, 0). If you have your mouse in the viewport's center, the ray direction should be equal to the camera's view direction. Please verify that.

Comment: My variables where indeed outdated but with 5000 FPS I doubt it would cause problems. I have updated and checked de ray direction with my camera direction and it was equal to a 0.0000001 error. the top left corner was indeed (0, 0) and the value written in `t` is the distance from the origin of the ray to the point of collision in units. I have also tried using my camera direction directly with the same result. I am using instancing and the object I check for has the translation data: `newdata[0].World = XMFLOAT3
       (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` and I check the vertices in an std::vector container.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I am using: `for(UINT i = 0; i < mVertices.size()/3; ++i)
  {
   
   // Vertices for this triangle.
   XMVECTOR v0 = XMLoadFloat3(&mVertices[(i*3)+0].Pos);
   XMVECTOR v1 = XMLoadFloat3(&mVertices[(i*3)+1].Pos);
   XMVECTOR v2 = XMLoadFloat3(&mVertices[(i*3)+2].Pos);` but I have already used the vector for my buffer:  `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = &mVertices[0];`. Could this change the data within? The working sample also does this but loads the data into the vector differently than I do.